# What conditions need to be met precisely to achieve PLA biodegradation?

Tags: pla, filament, recycling, biodegradability, composting

In addition to the question: [Can I really throw failed PLA prints on compost?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/3604/36802) and anything else I've read about PLA biodegradability, what **exact** conditions are needed to achieve this?

I mean, oxygen can be bought, and exposure to high temperatures for a specific time or light conditions can be arranged in a DIY matter. So, what conditions need to be met precisely to achieve PLA biodegradation? So far, I've never seen anyone provide a comprehensive list of required conditions or a DIY method.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylactic_acid#End_of_life cites https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S014139100700300X?via%3Dihub