# Is the term 'biodegradable' in the context of PLA misleading or misunderstood when industrial conditions are required to achieve it?

Tags: pla, terminology, biodegradability, composting, degradability

According to the Oxford Dictionary (Google), the definition of **biodegradability** is as follows:

> (of a substance or object) capable of being decomposed by bacteria or other living organisms and thereby avoiding pollution.

The definition for the term **composting** is:

> make (vegetable matter) into compost.

The definition for the term **compost** is:

> decayed organic material used as a fertilizer for growing plants.

The defintion for the term **decomposing** is:

> (of organic matter) in the process of decaying.

The general assumption is that "PLA can decompose in nature". However, it's no secret that PLA is only **degradable** under particular industry conditions, presumable using bacteria or other living organisms. Otherwise, it wouldn't even meet the definition **bio**degradable. The terms composting, compost, and decomposing do not apply to PLA, despite many speaking and writing about it.

At the very least, either the general understanding of the term "biodegradable" is wrong, or the term **biodegradable** is misleading, perhaps even greenwashing.

Related: [TEDx: Will PHA Replace All Plastic? Nouf Alhazmi](https://youtu.be/2EQ5fEbBt2Q?si=q9Wky4gahESOdkC_&t=395)

Comment: I'm genuinely interested in the question: 'Is the term 'biodegradable' misleading or misunderstood in the context of PLA when industrial conditions are required to achieve it?'. So, it's a matter of terminology. I'm using recycled PLA only but am considering switching entirely to PHA. Also see my other related question: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/21684/36802

Comment: Interesting Ted talk, makes you think of the term "biodegradeble". I knew it was hard to degrade PLA, not to this extent, nice question! But I think you already know the answer ;-)

Comment: Seems similar or related to [Can I really throw failed PLA prints on compost?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/3598/4762), which already has some answers. It seems as if answers to this question would equally apply to that question as well, so maybe a duplicate? The answer *seems* to be that no one *really* knows because PLA hasn't been around long enough to have decomposed yet, or in other words, we need to wait at least another 80 years or so, to be sure.

Comment: @Greenonline, that's seems to be an answer too, and I cannot imagine that no-one knows. CNC Kitchen did some tests. I saw other experiments on YouTube to speed up degradation with prolonged exposure of temperature and humidity for extended times without success. I don't think it's impossible, and I would like to find out how it is, which I asked in another question.

Comment: In addition I find very little info, tests and experiments about PHA filament properties. I just bought my first two spools of 100% PHA from colorfabb. I never printed anything else than recycled PLA. I will try to experiment, test, compare with PLA and post the results.